# What is astrological Devimana Ashtangam followed by the Shaktas?

Tags: astrology, shaktism, sri-vidya

Like the Panchangam of the jyotisha, we have the Ashtangam used by shaktas, what are its constituents ?

Answer (score 2):

It is a similar calculation of days like that of the Panchangam. It is useful for deciding daily worship and special parvas of the Shaktas.

> [kAla gaNanA](https://www.kamakotimandali.com/srividya/devimana.html) is accomplished normally by adopting pa~nchA~Nga
>   scheme which most of us are familiar with. The five angas are:
>
> 1. Tithi
> 2. nakShatra
> 3. yoga
> 4. karaNa
> 5. vAra
>
> Similarly, a parallel calendar is used by Srividyopasakas who have
>   undergone pUrNAbhiSheka, called devImAna aShTA~Nga. The source for
>   this scheme is Rudrayamala, Shaktiyamala, Paramananda Tantra,
>   Kaulikarnava, Tantraraja, Srigarbha Kularnava, Nathakrama patala of
>   Badabanala, Tripurasundari Tantra and works such as Saubhaya Tantra,
>   Saubhagya Chintamani, Dattareya Samhita, Saubhagyodaya, Nitya Kalpa,
>   Nathodaya, Kala Nitya Nirnaya, Durvasa Kalpa etc. The knowledge of
>   Ashtanga is considered very auspicious and important for a Srividya
>   Upasaka as it has various applications in Japa, Puja, Parayana, Kala
>   Nitya Krama etc. The Ashtangas are:
>
> 1. Yuga
> 2. Parivritti
> 3. Varsha
> 4. Masa
> 5. Divasa
> 6. Nityaa
> 7. Vasara
> 8. Ghatikodaya
>
> The number of yugas are: 36 Every Yuga has 36 Parivrttis Every
>   Parivrtti has 36 years Every year has 16 months Every month has 36
>   days Every month has 15+15 Nityas Every week has 9 days and so on.
>
> Devi herself pervades everything as kAlanityA and these form her
>   organs or avayavas. Like rashmi samkalana normally done applies to
>   desha sundarI, aShTa~Nga is applicable in terms of kAla sundarI. As
>   this refers only to kAla and not desha, samkalpa is incomplete if
>   performed only using aShTA~Nga, which is unfortunately followed by
>   most due to incorrect understanding of the Tantra. For the same
>   reason, Samkalpas printed in Srividya Nityahnikam, Kanchi Mutt
>   Panchangam, Coimbatore edition etc. should not be adopted directly.
>   The procedure for desha kirtana is to be learnt from Sadguru. Further,
>   Mahayuha, Kalpa, Mahakalpa, Natha Yuga, Nitya Yuga, Matrika Yuga and
>   other concepts are also used by Upaskas. Shodashanga and
>   Dvatrimshadangas are also known but less used due to complexity.
>
> On Aug 27, the new Parivrtti [daM chakShustattvAkhya] will start and
>   this will result in ten mahAyogas [from puShpiNI to chandroparAga] to
>   converge on the same day. This day is more auspicious can one can ever
>   imagine and occurs once in every 144 years. Worshiping Paradevata on
>   such a day will invite divine grace. This day is of greater
>   significance at Kanchipuram as Sage Durvasa performs Mahabhisehka and
>   another auspicious ritual to Sri Kamakshi on this sacred day in the
>   presence of all celestial deities. Those who behold the Sri Vigraha of
>   Kamakshi and the Salagrama Srichakra attain great merit. Japa, Homa,
>   Saparya, Tarpana, Brahmana Bhojana etc performed on this day
>   yieldgreat phala. Also, on this sacred day, the cycle of lopAmudrA
>   culminates and the age of Sri Bhairava commences. The Maha Samayaa for
>   this day is Jaya Durga, Nakshatra Yogini is Vajra Kubja, Dina Yogini
>   is Guhya Kali and soon. The Euphoria associated with this sacred day
>   can only be experienced and not expressed in words.
>
> darpA~Nkuro makaraketanavibhramANAm
>
> nindA~Nkuro vidalitotpalachaturINAm |
>
> dIpA~Nkuro bhavatamisrakadambakAnAm
>
> kAmAkShi palayatu mAm tvadapA~NgapAtaH ||